# How to use pytorch 0.4.1 model to init pytorch 0.2.0?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, pycaffe

I have met a problem that I train my model in `pytorch 0.4.1`, but I can't find a tool to convert it into `caffe` model.

How to use a `pytorch 0.4.1 model` to `init pytorch 0.2.0`?
Or how to convert a `pytorch 0.4.1 model` to a `caffe model`?

Comment: Are you using `Caffe2` or `Caffe` ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using `Caffe2`, you can use `ONNX` to convert models trained in one AI framework to another (with some limitations). In your case you need to export your `PyTorch` trained model to `ONNX` model and then import the `ONNX` model to `Caffe2` model.

Follow these tutorials:

`PyTorch` to `ONNX` export: [link](https://github.com/onnx/tutorials/blob/master/tutorials/PytorchOnnxExport.ipynb)

`ONNX` to `Caffe2` import: [link](https://github.com/onnx/tutorials/blob/master/tutorials/OnnxCaffe2Import.ipynb)

The tutorials are pretty straightforward, you don't need to write much code. But there are some limitations while exporting your `PyTorch` model to `ONNX`. 
 Check this link for in-depth tutorial on  [`Pytorch` to `ONNX`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/onnx.html).

Comment below if you have any doubts/ questions.

EDIT: Try this [repo](https://github.com/MTlab/onnx2caffe), I have tested it on a toy model it is working.

Comment: Using caffe not caffe2

Comment: Check my `EDIT`.